# Can I merge two views in Google analytics; tracked buttons and clicks analytics in one single dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to combine two views in one dashboard in google analytics report. I want the tracked buttons up and underneath the clicks analytics of my website.

Comment: Are you looking to solve this within Google Analytics, or other tools (and Google Analytics Reporting API) are relevant for you?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics views are self contained data.  There is no way to merge the data between two views.  Nor is there a way to preform analysis across multiple views.